# Login code returns to index page instead of moving forward

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want that when I select admin and enter username and password it should go to admin.html and if I enter details for student or teacher it goes to student.html and teacher.html respectively.

I am not able to find out the issue in the code. No error is logged but still it's not working. Database is already created in phpmyadmin with name `ezgradingsystem` that has a table named `loginform` with columns named `ID`, `username`, `password' and 'type' (that will differentiate between admin, teacher and student login).

Still it's not working. When I enter user name and password it takes me back to index.php page.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login Form </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles1.css"
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>

            <span>E</span>
            <span>Z</span>
            <span> </span>
             <span>G</span>
             <span>R</span>
             <span>A</span>
             <span>D</span>
             <span>I</span>
             <span>N</span>
             <span>G</span>
             <span> </span>
             <span>S</span>
             <span>Y</span>
             <span>S</span>
             <span>T</span>
             <span>E</span>
             <span>M</span>
              </h1>

        <div class="loginBox"> 
            <img src="user.png" alt="user" class="user"><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
                    <h2 >Log in Here</h2>
            <form  method="POST" >

                                <select name = "type">
                                <option value="-1">Login As
                                </option>
                                <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                <option value="Student">Student</option>
                                <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
                                </select></td>/


                <p>Username</p>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username here">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password here">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Sign In">



            </form>
                        <br><br><br>



                            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
$con =mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
    echo "unable to establish connection".mysql_error();
}
$db=mysql_select_db("ezgradingsystem",$con);
if(!$db)
{
    echo "Database not found".mysql_error();
}

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
     {

         $type=$_POST['type'];
         $username=$_POST['username'];
         $password=$_POST['pwd'];
         $query="select * from loginform where username='$username' and password ='$password'and type='$type'";
         $result=mysql_query($query);
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
             if($row['username']==$username && $row['password']==$password && $row['type']=='admin')
             {

                 header("Location: admin.html");
             }
             elseif($row['username'] ==$username && $row['password']==$password && row['type']=='student')

                 {

                 header("Location: student.html");
             }
             elseif($row['username']==$username && $row['password']==$password && row['type']=='teacher')

                 {

                 header("Location: teacher.html");
             }
         }
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: It would be better if you compare the username first.

Comment: you mean i insert the php code after </h1> ??

Comment: And I think what happens is that you didn't hit any of your `if/else` statements. First echo your username and password, plus check if you really are getting something from your query. If you have, echo the results. Also, you don't need to compare if the username and password is the same as from the database, because you have already compared them in the query, it is redundant. Just check if you have a result in the query or not, then check for the type

Comment: let me try this ..

Comment: no not getting username and password when i echo it after query

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure **mysql*-functions**. They have been **deprecated** since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to **[SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: i have used this tutorial for help to connect db https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrK4YaUKcf8

Comment: Do the admin/teacher/student pages check they are logged in ? I don't see any session creation or similar.

Comment: it was created before even i entered and i logged out too but then i edited the code to connect it to database and it all messed up

Comment: Also I don't see a $_POST['submit'] value being set since the submit button has no name.

Comment: shall i provide the code that i made first in which everything was working. That just doesn't have the database connected

Comment: @kmdm yeah .. i justed edited it let me see now

Comment: You also have $password=$_POST['pwd']; but the password field name is "password" not "pwd".

Comment: @kmdm thankyou so much its working now

Comment: yeah it has 2 errors as you told

Comment: 1) a $_POST['submit'] value being set since the submit button has no name. 2)$password=$_POST['pwd']; but the password field name is "password" not "pwd".   thankyou so much

Comment: let me see other options too

Comment: just admin one is working but two others are not

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use your type as your condition on `if` , try use this
    `

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {

     $type=$_POST['type'];
     $username=$_POST['username'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $query="select * from loginform where username='$username' and password ='$password'and type='$type'";
     $result=mysql_query($query);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
         if($type=='Admin')
         {

             header("Location: admin.html");
         }
         elseif($type=='Student')

             {

             header("Location: student.html");
         }
         elseif($type=='Teacher')

             {

             header("Location: teacher.html");
         }
     }
 }

?>`
```

Comment: or try use a level admin http://www.codefreax.net/2014/11/script-code-php-multi-user-secure-login-system.html

Comment: Oh yeah :) ? , So I will happy if you accept my answer :)